# How does JMS read multiple files on a queue

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, jms, camel-jms

The application that I am working on listens to a queue. This queue receives multiple files(Buy/Sell order)  from upstream. I am new to this application and trying to underatnsd how multiple files are process. We are using camel to listen to the queue. I understand that camel listens to the queue and when a file comes in it reads it and routes it to a java file to process it. My question is meanwhile a second or 100 messages arrives on the queue. How are these multiple files handles..would camel spawn a new thread to keep listening to messages while other thread routes it??

Comment: The camel-jms component uses Spring JMS that handles the threading model. So you can also find some information how Spring JMS works (eg its message container listener)

Answer (score 1):

> Would camel spawn a new thread to keep listening to messages while
>   other thread routes it?

This depends on your camel jms consumer setup for `concurrentConsumers` and `maxConcurrentConsumers`.

`concurrentConsumers` specify the initial number of concurrent consumer (listener thread/caller thread) for the route. Similarly,  `maxConcurrentConsumers` specify the maximum number of concurrent consumer for the route.

Camel will spawn a new thread for the jms route if `maxConcurrentConsumers` > `concurrentConsumers` and hit the limit for consumers.